# Artificial Login - Using HTML and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, authentication

I am attempting to create an artificial login page, using basic html and jQuery. Obviously, this would be not be used if attempting to create a "secure" login.

I've tried multiple solutions, but I have been continuing to have problems with the login.

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <input class="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
      <input class="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <button class="signInButton">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var username = $("input[name$='username']").val();
    var password = $("input[name$='password']").val();
    var signIn = $('.signInButton');

    signIn.on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (username === 'admin' && password === '1234') {
            alert('It Worked!');
            $(location).attr('href','http://google.com');
        } else {
            alert('Incorrect Username/Password.');
        }
    });

});
```

Ideally, upon submitting the correct values, the page should link elsewhere (for the purpose of this example, http://google.com).

To see the live example, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/y419usf0/).

Comment: What is your question and what error do you get currently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the variables inside the function, otherwise they are just set once on page load, and not reloaded on the click:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var signIn = $('.signInButton');

    signIn.on('click', function() {
        var username = $("input[name$='username']").val();
        var password = $("input[name$='password']").val();
        event.preventDefault();
        if (username === 'admin' && password === '1234') {
            alert('It Worked!');
            $(location).attr('href','http://google.com');
        } else {
            alert('Incorrect Username/Password.');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Beat me by 23 seconds!  I shouldn't have fixed it on JSFiddle first :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set your `username` and `password` variables inside the scope of your click function when it is executed.  Like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/y419usf0/5/

```
    signIn.on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $("input[name$='username']").val();
        var password = $("input[name$='password']").val();
        if (username === 'admin' && password === '1234') {
            alert('It Worked!');
            $(location).attr('href','http://google.com');
        } else {
            alert('Incorrect Username/Password.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think what @major-mann means is, it's not a scoping issue. This answer however, is correct.

Comment: I see what you mean @major-mann.  You're right that you can access the variables from the outer scope but they are incorrect when done that way.  Which is why I moved it inside the function.

Comment: Not *incorrect* per se. The `.val()` method simply gets the value of the inputs on page load, not when `signIn` is clicked, resulting in the `username` and `password` variables containing the *initial* input values.

Comment: I don't understand any of these comments. The inputs will be blank on page load - therefore why on earth would you want to re-check blank inputs that would never change? Once the val() executes, its assigned to the variable and won't change unless overriden within the scope. @Scott 23 seconds was tight but I needed the points :o)